# Merging two csv files together using php

Tags: php, csv

I have two sets of csv files - one containing the contracts data and the other containing the awarded contracts. I need to combine the two csv files using the common field (contractName) and compute the total amount of closed awarded contracts.[Link to the csv files](https://github.com/younginnovations/problem-statements/tree/master/clean-up-contracts-data)

So far I have managed to merge the two csv files together and write it in final.csv file but i am not being able to merget the two csv files using the common field(contractName). Here is the code.`

```
<?php
$nn = 0;
foreach (glob("*.csv") as $filename) {
    if (($handle = fopen($filename, "r")) !== FALSE) {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {

            $c = count($data);

            for ($x=0;$x<$c;$x++)
            {
                $csvarray[$nn][] = $data[$x];
            }
            $nn++;
        }

        fclose($handle);
    }

}

$fp = fopen('../final.csv', 'w');//output file set here

foreach ($csvarray as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

fclose($fp);?>
```

This is my final output.

```
contractName,contractDate,completionDate,awardee,awardeeLocation,Amount
Contract-2070-3,5/9/14,8/25/14,"SK Builders",Banke,200000
Contract-2070-5,3/18/14,4/8/14,"S engineering industries",Makwanpur,300000
Contract-2070-9,3/6/14,4/6/14,"Gourishankar nirman sewa",Lalitpur,400000
Contract-2070-10,2/6/14,6/16/14,"SK Builders",Banke,500000
contractname,status,bidPurchaseDeadline,bidSubmissionDeadline,bidOpeningDate,tenderid,publicationDate,publishedIn
Contract-2070-1,Closed,6/12/14,6/13/14,6/13/14,2070/071/2,5/14/14,"Nagarik Daily"
Contract-2070-2,Closed,6/10/14,6/11/14,6/11/14,16/070/71,5/12/14,"The Himalayan Times"
Contract-2070-3,Current,3/8/14,3/9/14,3/9/14,DDC/Bag/Bridge/03-070/71,3/10/14,"Nagarik Daily"
Contract-2070-4,Current,4/23/14,4/25/14,4/25/14,04(2070/071),4/9/14,"Hetauda sandesh"
Contract-2070-5,Closed,4/23/14,4/25/14,4/26/14,04(2070/071),4/10/14,"Hetauda sandesh"
Contract-2070-6,Current,4/23/14,4/25/14,4/27/14,04(2070/071),4/11/14,"Hetauda sandesh"
Contract-2070-7,Current,4/23/14,4/25/14,4/28/14,04(2070/071),4/12/14,"Hetauda sandesh"
Contract-2070-8,Current,4/23/14,4/25/14,4/29/14,04(2070/071),4/13/14,"Hetauda sandesh"
Contract-2070-9,Closed,2/6/14,2/8/14,2/8/14,15/070/71,1/9/14,"The Himalayan Times"
Contract-2070-10,Current,1/14/14,1/15/14,1/16/14,"13,2070/2071",1/6/14,"The Himalayan Times"
```

but the final output should be something like this.

```
contractname,status,bidPurchaseDeadline,bidSubmissionDeadline,bidOpeningDate,tenderid,publicationDate,publishedIn,contractDate,completionDate,awardee,awardeeLocation,Amount 
Contract-2070-1,Closed,6/12/14,6/13/14,6/13/14,2070/071/2,5/14/14,Nagarik Daily,,,,,
Contract-2070-2,Closed,6/10/14,6/11/14,6/11/14,16/070/71,5/12/14,The Himalayan Times,,,,,
Contract-2070-3,Current,3/8/14,3/9/14,3/9/14,DDC/Bag/Bridge/03-070/71,3/10/14,Nagarik Daily,5/9/14,8/25/14,SK Builders,Banke,200000
Contract-2070-4,Current,4/23/14,4/25/14,4/25/14,04(2070/071),4/9/14,Hetauda sandesh,,,,,
Contract-2070-5,Closed,4/23/14,4/25/14,4/26/14,04(2070/071),4/10/14,Hetauda sandesh,3/18/14,4/8/14,S engineering industries,Makwanpur,300000
Contract-2070-6,Current,4/23/14,4/25/14,4/27/14,04(2070/071),4/11/14,Hetauda sandesh,,,,,
Contract-2070-7,Current,4/23/14,4/25/14,4/28/14,04(2070/071),4/12/14,Hetauda sandesh,,,,,
Contract-2070-8,Current,4/23/14,4/25/14,4/29/14,04(2070/071),4/13/14,Hetauda sandesh,,,,,
Contract-2070-9,Closed,2/6/14,2/8/14,2/8/14,15/070/71,1/9/14,The Himalayan Times,3/6/14,4/6/14,Gourishankar nirman sewa,Lalitpur,400000
Contract-2070-10,Current,1/14/14,1/15/14,1/16/14,"13, 2070/2071",1/6/14,The Himalayan Times,2/6/14,6/16/14,SK Builders,Banke,500000
```

Comment: If a command line utility will suit you, you may try http://csvkit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/scripts/csvjoin.html

Comment: @Giovanni sorry i was told not to use command line. I need to do it through php. Is there any way. I am stuck right now.

Comment: @Giovanni i tried csvkit and it is very handy too but sadly i cant use it

Comment: Is this some kind of interview question? Do you need to show the ability to write the algorithm or to solve the problem in a realistic way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this problem isnt that hard, you always could put the data in those csv on array's and work with them, like this solution:

```
// 1st section
        $fh = fopen('awards.csv', 'r');
        $fhg = fopen('contracts.csv', 'r');
         while (($data = fgetcsv($fh, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            $awards[]=$data;
        }
        while (($data = fgetcsv($fhg, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {
                $contracts[]=$data;
        }
 // 2nd section   
        for($x=0;$x< count($contracts);$x++)
        {
            if($x==0){
                unset($awards[0][0]);
                $line[$x]=array_merge($contracts[0],$awards[0]); //header
            }
            else{
                $deadlook=0;
                for($y=0;$y <= count($awards);$y++)
                {
                    if($awards[$y][0] == $contracts[$x][0]){
                        unset($awards[$y][0]);
                        $line[$x]=array_merge($contracts[$x],$awards[$y]);
                        $deadlook=1;
                    }           
                }
                if($deadlook==0)
                    $line[$x]=$contracts[$x];
            }
        }
  // 3 section     
        $fp = fopen('final.csv', 'w');//output file set here

        foreach ($line as $fields) {
            fputcsv($fp, $fields);
        }
        fclose($fp);
```

is hard to me to explain the code, because iam from an spanish country, so my english isnt very good... but i can try

basically the code have 3 section,

in section 1, 
open those 2 file and put the content in an array $awards[] and $contracts[], so $awards[0] is the first line in awards.csv, $awards[1] is the second line in awards.csv, etc, the same in $contracts[].

in section 2,

i compare the first word in every array, $awards[x][0] and $contracts[x][0].

the first `if`, if($x==0), is to make the header.
first, i delete the first word `contractname` using `unset` function and join $awards[0] and $contracts[0] using `array_merge` function.

then, using those `for` i select the first word in every line from $contracts array and compare with the first word from every line from $awards array.
so, `if($awards[$y][0] == $contracts[$x][0])` check if those first word (ej. `Contract-2070-3are`) are the same, if those are the same string, delete it and merge those lines.

if those word arent the same, save the $contracts[x] line in $line array and continue.

in section 3,
save the content from $line array in the file.

Comment: thank u man it worked. Now i am trying to understand the code. Thank u so so much man. U r awesome and GENIUS

Comment: Can u please tell me how to solve problem like this? I mean how to make algorithms. I am a newbie and I am very willing to learn

Comment: check and if you have a question i can try to explain, but i recomended that you try to read a few more of algorithms and data structures, check here if any of those link can help you http://www.quora.com/Are-there-any-good-sites-for-learning-algorithm-programming-concepts-every-day-similar-to-the-SAT-question-of-the-day

Comment: ur english is better than mine :D but believe me ur code does all the talking :D

Answer (score 0):

Is this some kind of interview question? Do you need to show the ability to write the algorithm or to solve the problem in a realistic way?

For a big data set, I would probably just dump the csv to a sqlite db, one table per csv, and the join them with a query.

Or you may populate two associative arrays with each csv, $contracts and $awards, using the joining field (contractName) as key for both arrays.
Then you cicle the keys, and populate a $final array with the content of each array for the given key:

```
$final = array();
$keys = array_keys($contracts);
foreach($keys as $key) {
    $final[] = array_merge($contracts[$key], $awards[$key]);
}
```

Comment: this is not an interview question. It is a part of my learning algorithms and I realized as i am a noob that it is very hard.