# PHP How can I combine two CSVs based on common fields in a rows of each csv?

Tags: php, csv, fgetcsv

I have two CSVs:

1st csv is something like this:

```
number | color | size | animal

**1234** | black | big | cat
```

2nd csv is like this:

```
name | country | os | number | flavour | yesorno

john | world | windows | **1234** | good | yes
```

What I'm trying to do is to merge both CSV's (header titles and values of each row) based on matching number values:

```
number | color | size | animal | name | country | os | flavour | yesorno

**1234** | black | big | cat | john | world | windows | good | yes
```

I have been trying to use `fgetcsv` and used keys but I am really a newbie to php and I do not know how to that. I need to understand the logic. Could anyone please help?

Many thanks.

-- edit for better udnerstanding --
based on another question on stackoverflow, I have tryed the following code, which is not working well. The two headers from both CSV files is not merged. It is also missing all the data from a csv, it only has one row of data merged.

Code was found in another question: [Merging two csv files together using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26440839/merging-two-csv-files-together-using-php) and seemed like a perfect base for what I am trying to achieve. Unfortunately the outputed csv is malformed...

```
<?php
// 1st section
$fh  = fopen('csv1.csv', 'r');
$fhg = fopen('csv2.csv', 'r');

while (($data = fgetcsv($fh, 0, ";")) !== FALSE) {
    $csv1[] = $data;
}
while (($data = fgetcsv($fhg, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $csv2[] = $data;
}

// 2nd section

for ($x = 0; $x < count($csv2data); $x++) {
    if ($x == 0) {
        unset($csv1data[0][17]);
        $line[$x] = array_merge($csv2data[0], $csv1data[17]); //header
    } else {
        $deadlook = 0;
        for ($y = 0; $y <= count($csv1data); $y++) {

            if($csv1data[$y][17] == $csv2data[$x][0]){
            unset($csv1data[$y][17]);
            $line[$x]=array_merge($csv2data[$x],$csv1data[$y]);
            $deadlook=1;
            }
        }
        if ($deadlook == 0)
            $line[$x] = $csv2data[$x];
    }
}
// 3 section    
$fp = fopen('final.csv', 'w'); //output file set here

foreach ($line as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Comment: How did u try to use `fgetcsv`? Please show some effort

Comment: @Trix : I have edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
     $fh = fopen('csv1', 'r');
        $fhg = fopen('csv2', 'r');
         while (($data = fgetcsv($fh, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            $csv1[]=$data;
        }
        while (($data = fgetcsv($fhg, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {
                $csv2[]=$data;
        }
 // 2nd section
        for($x=0;$x< count($csv2);$x++)
        {
            if($x==0){
                unset($csv1[0][0]);
                $line[$x]=array_merge($csv2[0],$csv1[0]); //header
            }
            else{
                $deadlook=0;
                for($y=0;$y <= count($csv1);$y++)
                {
                    if($csv1[$y][0] == $csv2[$x][0]){
                        unset($csv1[$y][0]);
                        $line[$x]=array_merge($csv2[$x],$csv1[$y]);
                        $deadlook=1;
                    }
                }
                if($deadlook==0)
                    $line[$x]=$csv2[$x];
            }
        }
  // 3 section
        $fp = fopen('final.csv', 'w');//output file set here

        foreach ($line as $fields) {
            fputcsv($fp, $fields);
        }
        fclose($fp);
```

> In section 1

open those 2 file and put the content in an array $csv1[] and $csv2[], so $csv1[0] is the first line in csv1.csv, $csv1[1] is the second line in csv1.csv, etc, the same in $csv2[].

> In section 2,

i compare the first word in every array, $csv1[x][0] and $csv2[x][0].

the first if, if($x==0), is to make the header. first, i delete the first word contractname using unset function and join $csv1[0] and $csv2[0] using array_merge function.

then, using those for i select the first word in every line from $csv2 array and compare with the first word from every line from $csv1 array. so, if($csv1[$y][0] == $csv2[$x][0]) check if those first word  are the same, if those are the same string, delete it and merge those lines.

if those word arent the same, save the $csv2[x] line in $line array and continue.

> In section 3,

save the content from $line array in the file.

Comment: Thanks but it is not working I am getting error Notice: "Undefined offset: 0 on line 21" and "Undefined offset: 19 on line 21" . These errors correspond to :  if($csv1[$y][0] == $csv2[$x][0])  , I think.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $fromFile = fopen($REcsv,'r');
    $fromFile2 = fopen($pathToFile,'r');
    $toFile = fopen($reportFile,'w');
    $delimiter = ';';
    $line = fgetcsv($fromFile, 65536, $delimiter);
    $line2 = fgetcsv($fromFile2, 65536, $delimiter);

    while ($line !== false) {
        while ($line2 !== false) {
            fputcsv($toFile, array_merge($line2,$line), $delimiter);
            $line = fgetcsv($fromFile, 65536, $delimiter);
            $line2 = fgetcsv($fromFile2, 65536, $delimiter);
        }
    }
    fclose($fromFile);
    fclose($fromFile2);
    fclose($toFile);
```